# Link to Excel Worksheet with Linked Cell in Upper Left

Tags: .net, excel, vba

I am generating an Excell spreadsheet in a .NET application.  The file has two sheets.  The first is a cover sheet with deep links into the data, which is in the second sheet. When a link is clicked, the second sheet opens to that cell, with the position of the cell in the lower left corner.  I need it to open with the cell in the upper right corner.

I'm pretty sure there is no way to make this happen in the .NET code that is generating the file.  (But if I'm wrong, please tell me.)  However, I did find some other discussions about this, and the solution seems to be to add a little but of VB code to the Excel file itself.  Meaning, to the template file that is used to seed the data and produce the final file.

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Application.Goto ActiveCell, True
End Sub
```

Thing is, I really don't know what to do with this code.  I could benefit from some step-by-step instructions... like, assume I'm a total and complete idiot newbie when it comes to Excel (which actually, I am.)

Thanks!!

Comment: Can't you just set the hyperlink to point to the cell you want to link to?  E.g. in VBA the code might look like `    Worksheets("Sheet1").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), Address:="", SubAddress:="Sheet2!H1", TextToDisplay:="Follow this link"
`.  It should be something similar in .Net.

Comment: Of course we can set the hyperlink to the cell we want to link to.  But the problem is, that cell ends up in the lower left corner of the window. We want it in the upper left corner.

Comment: Ahh - so it is nothing to do with the hyperlink - your question is "how can I display a sheet such that cell x is in the top left corner".  (I was reading it as the hyperlink was taking you to a cell at the bottom left corner of the sheet.)

Comment: `with the position of the cell in the lower left corner` - I have tried all sorts of things and can't replicate this behaviour in a general situation.  The GoTo will force the cell to the top-left corner, so I assume you were experiencing it before adding the GoTo.  But the only way I can end up with the cell in the lower-left is if it was already in that exact position when the hyperlink was clicked.  Weird.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will first go to the cell which is one column to the right of the target, placing it in the top left corner.  It then shifts the window one page to the left, and then selects the original target again without scrolling.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Application.Goto ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), True
    ActiveWindow.LargeScroll ToLeft:=1
    Application.Goto ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1), False
End Sub
```

I'm not sure what will happen if your target is, for instance, cell B100 - the window shift to the left may or may not work.

P.S.  This code should be placed into the code module for the worksheet containing the hyperlinks.

Comment: I'm not sure why your question says that the cell was opening in the bottom-left corner.  Mine was always opening in the top-left corner.  I might have a play and see if I can replicate how you are getting your behaviour - it might require another tweak to the code.

Comment: Thank you for the code!  However, my real question is... WHAT DO I DO WITH THIS CODE??  I have no idea where it goes inside Excel.  As I said in the OP,  I am really hoping for idiot proof steps on where to put this code, and how to save it.

Comment: Open your template file, go to the Macro editor (different method on different versions of Excel, but try Alt-F11), in the Project window on the left-hand-side double-click the sheet that contains the hyperlinks, paste the code into the main "code" window (possibly empty at the moment?), close the macro editor, save the template file.

Comment: Here's the link to the SO documentation on how to open the VBE - http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/777/introduction-to-excel-vba/2801/opening-the-visual-basic-editor#t=201608242116238997309

Comment: @CaseyCrookston - sorry, the second link showed how to add code to a non-worksheet code module.  (I've deleted that comment now.)  You will need to follow the instruction in my earlier comment instead (`in the Project window on the left-hand-side double-click the sheet that contains the hyperlinks, paste the code into the main "code" window (possibly empty at the moment?`).

Comment: thanks!  I will give this a try today and report back.